# All Traffic Channels - Total 'Users' count issue

Tags: google-analytics

I just wanted to see if anyone has had the same issue as I've just encountered.

I'm in the process of creating a report and gone into 'Acquisition > All Traffic Channels'. I'm then given the following information:

[image]

So the weird thing that has come up is that the total user number is 1,709 yet when you add the 6 rows figures together, you are given the result of 1,793, a difference of 84.

The information in the image shows 100% of the users and there are no other rows to show so this is all of the data accessible. If i go to 'Audience > Overivew', i'm shown 1,709 as I'd expect (matching the other areas of the site) but this figure is wrong...

Has anyone else encountered this issue and if so, is there a reason for this?

Thanks all!

Mark Ferguson

Comment: A lot of things in Google Analytics are not real-time and rely on backend processes doing periodic updates. I suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: So the dates I'm working with are 15th April to 15th May so this isn't real-time data and the really weird thing is that the simple calculation is wrong rather than any information is being missed. 100% of the data is being analysed as per the screenshot. This has left me baffled!

Answer (score 1):

In the acquisition report, you can have users who are multi-channel. Thus why it doesn't add up because one user can be for two or more channels.

Comment: After talking with Google Support, they were even unsure as to what the reason why this is happening (which doesn't really help!). Think I was sort of fobbed off by saying that this has been passed on to the development team and they will look into this. They mentioned also that 'additional unique users' will be added to the channels and that the total user number is an estimation. Was quite confused by this and the woman I spoke to couldn't really give me any further clarification...

Answer (score 0):

This happen because a same user may lands on your website from different channel.
For example, if you land on the website yesterday from Facebook and today from Organic, you are still 1 user as total but you appear 1 on Facebook and 1 on Organic Search.